# I'm creating a service to read SMS messages, but when I run it I get an error

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

The error I get is "Unfortunately, service has stopped working", where service is the name of my app. The question is similar to my previous questions, but here I'm doing something completely different - trying to read SMS messages.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button start, stop;

        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button1);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2);

        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

        public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent service = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);

        startService(service);

        }

        });

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override

          public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent name = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);

        stopService(name);

        }

        });

        }

}
```

My service file, MyService.java:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    final static String ACTION = "NotifyServiceAction";
    final static String STOP_SERVICE = "";
    final static int RQS_STOP_SERVICE = 1;
    private SMSreceiver  mSMSreceiver;
    private IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
    SMSreceiver notifyServiceReceiver;

    private static final int MY_NOTIFICATION_ID=1;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private Notification myNotification;
    private final String myBlog = "http://android-er.blogspot.com/";


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        notifyServiceReceiver = new SMSreceiver ();
        mSMSreceiver = new SMSreceiver();
        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(mSMSreceiver, mIntentFilter);

        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("MyService","Service started");
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(ACTION);
        registerReceiver(notifyServiceReceiver, intentFilter);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.i("MyService","Service destroyed");
        this.unregisterReceiver(mSMSreceiver);
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    private class SMSreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
        private final String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            String strMessage = "";

            if ( extras != null )
            {
                Object[] smsextras = (Object[]) extras.get( "pdus" );

                for ( int i = 0; i < smsextras.length; i++ )
                {
                    SmsMessage smsmsg = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsextras[i]);

                    String strMsgBody = smsmsg.getMessageBody().toString();
                    String strMsgSrc = smsmsg.getOriginatingAddress();

                    strMessage += "SMS from " + strMsgSrc + " : " + strMsgBody;                    

                    Log.i(TAG, strMessage);
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Service manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="yash.my.service"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name="yash.my.service.MyService$SMSreceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="999"> 
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
        <activity
            android:name="yash.my.service.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The error is shown once I send an SMS to the AVD. I will also post the log:

```
04-20 16:00:45.555: E/Trace(1085): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
04-20 16:00:46.793: D/gralloc_goldfish(1085): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-20 16:00:50.203: I/MyService(1085): Service started
04-20 16:01:05.933: D/AndroidRuntime(1085): Shutting down VM
04-20 16:01:05.933: W/dalvikvm(1085): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver yash.my.service.MyService.SMSreceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "yash.my.service.MyService.SMSreceiver" on path: /data/app/yash.my.service-1.apk
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2357)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "yash.my.service.MyService.SMSreceiver" on path: /data/app/yash.my.service-1.apk
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2352)
04-20 16:01:05.943: E/AndroidRuntime(1085):     ... 10 more
04-20 16:01:06.203: D/dalvikvm(1085): GC_CONCURRENT freed 106K, 8% free 2692K/2916K, paused 75ms+2ms, total 213ms
```

**NEW LOGCAT, AFTER UPDATING CODE:**

```
04-20 16:33:41.163: I/MyService(1304): Service started
04-20 16:33:56.355: D/dalvikvm(1304): newInstance failed: no <init>()
04-20 16:33:56.355: D/AndroidRuntime(1304): Shutting down VM
04-20 16:33:56.363: W/dalvikvm(1304): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver yash.my.service.MyService$SMSreceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class yash.my.service.MyService$SMSreceiver; no empty constructor
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2357)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class yash.my.service.MyService$SMSreceiver; no empty constructor
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2352)
04-20 16:33:56.483: E/AndroidRuntime(1304):     ... 10 more
04-20 16:33:56.613: D/dalvikvm(1304): GC_CONCURRENT freed 119K, 9% free 2692K/2928K, paused 75ms+3ms, total 214ms
```

Comment: have you register the service in manifest?

Comment: Yes, I have registered the service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an inner class in your manifest you need to use a $ to separate it from the parent class.

```
com.example.ParentClass$InnerClass
```

It also needs to be public and static.

Comment: Updated the code and posted the LogCat results. I should change the receiver manifest code to `<receiver android:name="yash.my.service.MyService$SMSreceiver">`, right?

Comment: Yes, but also, SMSReceiver should be 'public static class SMSreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver'